# How to propagate an event to a different stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, events, window, javafx, stage

Here is my problem: In JavaFX the event system propagates to the `Stage` node and stops there. In my current project I have two stages:

- The primary stage in `Main`
- Another stage created in an FXML Controller

Inside the secondary stage, the controller fires a custom event, but since it stops at the secondary stage it doesn't get caught in my primary stage.

My question is: how would I go about getting my custom event to propagate in the hierarchy of the primary stage.

If you're wondering, the purpose of this is to create a popup window with custom formatting from an FXML file.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: what Modality you have used in the stages? is it Modality.NONE or Modality.WINDOW_MODAL or Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL

Comment: It's a custom stage with the APPLICATION_MODAL modality.(the secondary stage)

Comment: javafx docs says Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL - a stage that blocks input events from being delivered to all windows from the same application, except for those from its child hierarchy. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html

Comment: Tested with Modality.NONE, it still apparently doesn't propagate.

Comment: may be the buildEventDispatchChain() of stage might help. I have not used it. Hope this will help